# Does Jmeter support client side javascript

Tags: jmeter

Does Jmeter support client side javascript. I am able to record the script but replay log doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMeter is not a browser, it's a load generation tool. It can produce HTTP traffic, but it does not actually parse/execute JavaScript coming with the loaded page.

If you need to load test your AJAX application, then you can easily simulate HTTP traffic coming from normal browser requests and from AJAX requests.

For functional browser testing I would recommend using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 1):

No. JMeter does not process Javascript or applets embedded in HTML pages.

JMeter can download the relevant resources (some embedded resources are downloaded automatically if the correct options are set), but it does not process the HTML and execute any Javascript functions.

If the page uses Javascript to build up a URL or submit a form, you can use the Proxy Recording facility to create the necessary sampler. If this is not possible, then manual inspection of the code may be needed to determine what the Javascript is doing.