# Calling application javascript function

Tags: jmeter

```
coSelectAll();
coUnSelectAll();
```

These function above are part of our application and when I run on chrome console it select and unselect a company structure. How can I call these functions from `jmeter` as I heard *jmeter does not have access to DOM*. I am a newbie so forgive me if this is a silly questions. What options are available in jmeter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Jmeter support client side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632492/does-jmeter-support-client-side-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

- If these functions generate [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) you should be able to record and replay them using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).
- If these functions affect UI only (i.e. check some boxes or something like that) you won't be able to do test it using JMeter, as per JMeter project main page

  > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.**

Real browsers send HTTP Requests and render the response. JMeter can mimic sending any HTTP requests via [HTTP Request samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) so from application under test perspective it won't be different from real user, but JavaScript is executed solely on client side so if it doesn't trigger any network activity - the server doesn't know anything about what is happening in the browser on client side.

If your test scenario assumes checking selection/deselection of company structure via invoking certain JavaScript functions consider switching to [Selenium browser automation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) framework. Also be aware that there is a Selenium integration with JMeter via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as this is exactly what I needed to know