# Performance Testing ReactJS components using Performance Testing tool

Tags: apache, performance, reactjs, jmeter, performance-testing

I am testing ReactJS application for performance perspective with Jmeter tool

After executing Login feature, Response data in "View Results in Tree" shows following:

> JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser. You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Jmeter support client side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632492/does-jmeter-support-client-side-javascript)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: duplicate to many other similar questions, another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344112/jmeter-and-javascript

Comment: You need a stronger architectural foundation to use performance testing tools.  You should not expect an HTTP tool to execute your client side script